# I want the COUNTA function to not count the "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to add a "COUNTA" function to this formula. But I get "1" as a result when it should be 0. I guess it is counting my "0". How can I solve this issue?

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Assignments Data Export 05 12'!$D:$D;
    (('Assignments Data Export 05 12'!$F:$F=$A$8)*
    ('Assignments Data Export 05 12'!$BZ:$BZ=$B10)*
    ('Assignments Data Export 05 12'!$L:$L=$C$19)*
    ('Assignments Data Export 05 12'!$BX:$BX>$C$18)));"0")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesnt work ... my filter formula returns a "#calc! so it will count 1

Comment: Ah yes. Why not just use COUNTIFS here instead of the IFERROR/FILTER.

Comment: If you would want to count the number meeting certain condition you could use the conditions and wrap it in SUM or SUMPRODUCT. If it's one condition: `=SUM (--(Range=Condition))` for multiple: `=SUM((Range1=Condition1)*(Range2=Condition2))` or use COUNTIF(S) as suggested by BigBen